# How to set focus to the div when button click in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to set focus to the `div` which is top of the page when clicking the button. It means it validates when click the button, if validation fails, it need to focus the top of the page, where the validation error shows.

So how to get the focus the top of the page div. And form is in `modal-dialog`.

Comment: have you tried this angular.element('#<elementId>').focus(); ? or else there are many onfocus directive to handle this.

Comment: I tried, but not working

Answer (score 17):

> If you want to make a non-focusable element focusable, you must add a
>   tabindex attribute to it and `div` falls in that category .

More on [`tabIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)

use some thing like this

```
<div tabindex="1"></div>
```

or even make a directive for the same which will help you customize the functionality

```
import { Directive, Input, ElementRef, Inject, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[focusField]' })
export class FocusDirective implements OnChanges {

  @Input('focusField') focusField: any;
  constructor(@Inject(ElementRef) private element: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnChanges(changes){
    if(changes.focusField.currentValue){
      this.element.nativeElement.focus();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the solution with Directives.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to add a **@ViewChild** in your component and use **.nativeElement.focus()**

*component html :*

```
<div #myerr class="my-error">{{myError}}</div>
```

*component ts :*

```
 export class YourComponent implements AfterViewInit {
   @ViewChild('myerr') myErrorText: ElementRef;


  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.myErrorText.nativeElement.focus();
  }
}
```

You can change ngAfterViewInit() by your triggering function.
If you want, you can give me your code and I adapt my answer.

Comment: this is not working giving error **ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined**